# Python Pandas - Replacing relevant texts fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns - primary column and secondary column. The secondary column might have a(.) or a text like " (On Leave) after the desired string.

```
I learned that to replace ("."), it has to be passed with ("\.")
```

If the secondary column holds a particular value like "NOTAPPLICABLEHERE" then I am taking the result as True.

To do this, I created a variable called as -

Exceptions = "NOTAPPLICABLEHERE"

And the below code is what I wrote,

```
temp_result_df[res_col_name]  = (temp_result_df[primaryreportreqcolname].eq(temp_result_df[RequiredSecondaryReport_Col_Name].str.replace \
                                ('\.'|' (On Leave)', '', regex = True)) | (temp_result_df[RequiredSecondaryReport_Col_Name]== Exceptions))
```

And it fails with an error saying - unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'.

```
PrimaryColumn   SecondaryColumn    ExpectedOutput
Mr               Mr.                  True
Jr               Jr                   True
Mrs              Mrs                  True
Mr               Mrs                  False
Mr               Mr (On Leave)        True
Mr               NOTAPPLICABLEHERE    True
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is regex problem - need escape `()` and remove `''` around `|`:

```
p = 'PrimaryColumn'
s = 'SecondaryColumn'

Exceptions = "NOTAPPLICABLEHERE"

df['new']  = df[p].eq(df[s].str.replace(r'\.| \(On Leave\)', '')) | (df[s] == Exceptions)
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df[p].eq(df[s].replace(r'\.| \(On Leave\)', '', regex = True)) | 
            (df[s ]== Exceptions)
```

---

```
print (df)
  PrimaryColumn    SecondaryColumn  ExpectedOutput    new
0            Mr                Mr.            True   True
1            Jr                 Jr            True   True
2           Mrs                Mrs            True   True
3            Mr                Mrs           False  False
4            Mr      Mr (On Leave)            True   True
5            Mr  NOTAPPLICABLEHERE            True   True
```

Comment: It says this - replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'

Comment: @Sid29 - because `.str.replace`, so remove `regex=True` or use only `.replace`

Comment: Worked. Thank you.